# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=1} ^ n \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \right)= e^{\int_0 ^1 f(x)dx} $

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I have been trying to show that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function then
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{k=1} ^ n  \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)  \right)= e^{\int_0 ^1 f(x)dx} $$

I have tried some approaches to prove this but couldn't find a way. Can someone kindly help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Take logarithms and use the fact that $(1-\epsilon) x \leq \log (1+x) \leq x$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$.

Comment: This makes sense only if $\left[ {0,1} \right] \subseteq \left[ {a,b} \right]$.

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral